# How to store state in Windows 8.1 using Blank Page Template?

Tags: c#, windows-8.1

I am migrating my Windows Phone 8 App to Windows 8.1 App and I have created a Page with blank page template. In that there are some Items like TextBlock,ComboBox and TextBox. Now, there is an item LocationTextBlock with border around it. When I click on it, it navigates to a new Page *LocationPage*, where I need to select location and save that object and navigate using *Frame.GoBack()* method. Now the issue, when I navigate back, I get the object of LocationData but the LocationTextBlock which was created previously is showing null, so I can't populate Location in that TextBlock.

Questions

1. Is this issue occurring due to Blank Page Template ?
2. Can it be solved using NavigationHelper Class?
3. Will using Basic Page Template resolve this issue?

Please suggest with some code or description, whether it can be done using Blank Page template as I have added many lines of code inside it.

Comment: `...I get the object of LocationData but the LocationTextBlock which was created previously is showing null`- do you mean `LocationTextBlock` is null after you navigate back?

Comment: @kennyzx Yes LocationTextBlock is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done with Blank Page template (although using NavigationHelper would be the prefered way).
What you have to do is set NavigationCacheMode to Enabled in your Page's Constructor:

```
this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Enabled;
```

This way the Page with all the properties in it is cached. So when you navigate back you get back the state in which the Page was when you navigated from it. However, if you navigate to this page not through backnavigation, you'll still get back the saved state, which you don't want. The solution is to clean up all the resources (initializing the needed variables, setting UI elements to default value etc.) in the `OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)` method `if (e.NavigationMode != NavigationMode.Back)`. Don't know if it's the best approach, but it'll work.

EDIT:

You could even use a Flyout or a ContentDialog instead of your LocationPage, so you don't need to navigate from the page, thus not needing to cache/save the page.

Comment: it worked as expected, but are there any issues with enabling the NavigationCacheMode?

Comment: It didn't cause any issues for me so far :). You can read on this topic here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page.navigationcachemode

Comment: my app is crashing when I again open the same page, except back navigation.Please suggest what should I do to resolve that? And its my need to use a different page for Location.

Comment: It is enough if you post what you do if the navigationmode is not backnavigation!

Comment: In NavigationMode.New, I am getting a string object using e.parameter. toString() method. That's all. Like  'formid=e.Parameter. to string();'

Comment: you should check if the parameter is null. Maybe it is crashing when you don't pass anything to the page.

Comment: I have a new problem, I have a page with image, when I rotate the stimulator, the image gets rotated but its gets stretched. Can you suggest anything for this??